# Redis Queue info in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am learning how to use Redis Queue. I am using Window 8.1 XAMPP. I have successfully implemented Database queue. So far, as per this article: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redis I have installed package in `composer require predis/predis`

I took subscription which is limited to 30MB for testing from here: https://app.redislabs.com

In config/queue.php, I saw the below code.

```
'redis' => [
    'driver'        => 'redis',
    'connection'    => 'default',
    'queue'         => 'default',
    'retry_after'   => 90,
],
```

Below is the code in config/database.php but my default database is mysql

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host'      =>  env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password'  =>  env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port'      =>  env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database'  =>  0,
    ],

],
```

My Question is: where should i get the info for redis for above two sections?

I already checked by selecting the Database->Configuration Tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the connection information for your Redis Cloud instance:

1. Login to the dashboard
2. Select the database
3. Click the 'Configuration' tab

The host, port & password are obtainable from there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this info is not present there. I have already visited the dashboard page. There I selected the Database and then in configuration tab there was no info about host, port and password. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCO4d.png

Comment: The host and port are what makes the endpoint. Looks like your password is empty. In any case, please don't hesitate to contact our support team at support@redislabs.com with any question.